# 3D-world, autonomous agents basics processing

Tags: processing

I'd like to design code that creates a 3D-processing world where a building is created of multiple stacked boxes. I want to use autonomous agents that are influenced by some forces like wind for example.
This is something i use for example: http://cdn.home-designing.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/stacked-box-dollhouse.jpg (don't know how to post it in a different way, it's my first time using this forum)

Can anyone help me getting started creating this kind of 'building' in the first place. Or if you have a similar example that can help me get started, that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm afraid that your question is way too broad for this site. Look for some tutorials that get you started with simple examples and please feel free to come back with specific problems and questions regarding the things you'll have tried yourself. Good luck and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

This is going to get very difficult in 3D – for 2D, the excellent [Box2D library](https://github.com/shiffman/Box2D-for-Processing) handles physics and collision. Daniel Shiffman, who also ported the library to Processing, has some great tutorials in his ["Nature of Code" book](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-5-physics-libraries/), which you can read online for free.

Comment: The better way – use a game engine like Unity. I know it's not Processing, but it will certainly handle all the 3D things much more easily.